# Appending new rows to the data.frame in a loop

Tags: r, loops

I am scraping a table for a list of ID's.

This is my list:

```
dput(temp_data)
structure(list(tax_number = c("http://www.ujp.gov.mk/mk/prebaruvanje_pravni_lica/prikazi?edb=MK4020012521389", 
"http://www.ujp.gov.mk/mk/prebaruvanje_pravni_lica/prikazi?edb=MK4026009507659", 
"http://www.ujp.gov.mk/mk/prebaruvanje_pravni_lica/prikazi?edb=MK4013009503390", 
"http://www.ujp.gov.mk/mk/prebaruvanje_pravni_lica/prikazi?edb=MK4026010510230", 
"http://www.ujp.gov.mk/mk/prebaruvanje_pravni_lica/prikazi?edb=MK4080009506819", 
"http://www.ujp.gov.mk/mk/prebaruvanje_pravni_lica/prikazi?edb=MK4066010500147", 
"http://www.ujp.gov.mk/mk/prebaruvanje_pravni_lica/prikazi?edb=MK4026013516794", 
"http://www.ujp.gov.mk/mk/prebaruvanje_pravni_lica/prikazi?edb=MK4020012520196", 
"http://www.ujp.gov.mk/mk/prebaruvanje_pravni_lica/prikazi?edb=MK4020008505166", 
"http://www.ujp.gov.mk/mk/prebaruvanje_pravni_lica/prikazi?edb=MK4020010511645"
)), .Names = "tax_number", row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

The libraries and loop im using:

```
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
library(tidyr)


for (i in 1:nrow(temp_data)) {

  temp_data_point <- temp_data[i, ]
  file <- read_html(temp_data_point)
  tables <- html_nodes(file, "table")
  table1 <- html_table(tables[8], fill = TRUE)
  table2 <- as.data.frame(table1)
  table2 <- table2[15:24 , 1:2]

  colnames(table2)[1] <- "variables"
  colnames(table2)[2] <- "results"

  temp_table <- spread(table2, variables, results)
  temp[i, ] <- temp_table
  return(temp)
}
```

So basically, the loop iterates through the list, filling the data into the temp object, but my code doesnt record each iteration in a seperate row with the

```
temp[i, ] <- temp_table
```

Instead, Im getting only the last iteration.

Any ideas where Im getting it wrong?

P.S.

I forgot to mention. The object temp is an object created outside of the loop.

```
str(temp)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ Адреса        : chr "БУЛ.МАК.ПРОСВЕТИТЕЛИ 16"
 $ Дејност       : chr "Дејности на туристичките агенции"
 $ Депонент банка: chr "ОХРИДСКА БАНКА А.Д. - ОХРИД"
 $ ЕДБ           : chr "MK4020012521389"
 $ Жиро сметка   : chr "000530000101546566"
 $ Матичен број  : chr "6823769"
 $ Место         : chr "ОХРИД"
 $ Назив         : chr "Трговско друштво за производство градеЖништво трговија услуги и угостителство  АНТОНИО&БОЈАН ДООЕЛ увоз-извоз Охрид"
 $ Правна форма  : chr "Д.О.О.Е.Л. ДРУШТВО СО ОГРАНИЧЕНА ОДГОВОРНОСТ НА ЕДНО ЛИЦЕ"
 $ Телефон       : chr "075/414-585"
```

It basically has the same column names, and one dummy row.

Comment: where did you create the object `temp`?

Comment: Note that `colnames(table2)[1] <- "variables"; colnames(table2)[2] <- "results"` can be written `names(table2) <- c("variables", "results")`.

Comment: @NateDay hi. I just updated the question. I forgot to mention that the temp object was created outside of the loop.

Comment: @Imo thanks for the advice!

Comment: It looks like `temp_table` is a data.frame, if it is it will be difficult to add it to an existing data.frame (`temp`) as a row at a predefined index. You might be better off using `temp <- list()` as your container variable and adding each loop's result as `temp[[i]] <- temp_table`. Then after the loop do a `do.call(rbind, temp)` to stack up results row-wise as a data.frame. Also you won't need that `return(temp)` in your for loop, with that list building strategy

Comment: @Nate Day the approach worked. Thanks for the alternative solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your function returns immediatelly after initializing the first row of the `data.frame`. Take the `return` outside of the loop, e.g:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(temp_data)) {
  ...
  temp[i, ] <- temp_table
}

return(temp)
```

Comment: I should've thought on that. Thank you for the help Erhan!